# SASS/SCSS Avoid duplicate properties including two mixins or extending two classes

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

Let's say that I have two classes that I can `@extend` (or two mixins I can `@include`) like so:

```
.small-text {
    font-family: "MyFontFamily";
    color: black;
    line-height: 1rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

.large-text {
    font-family: "MyFontFamily";
    color: black;
    line-height: 1.4rem;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}
```

Now, all throughout my SCSS, I can do things like this:

```
h1 {
    @extend .large-text;
}

h3 {
    @extend .small-text;
}
```

But now let's say that I want to use a class name, *or a media query*, to selective change from small to large text:

```
h3 {
    @extend .small-text;
    
    &.big {
        @extend .large-text;
    }
}
```

**The problem** I'm having is the the compiled CSS is going to be really duplicative, like so:

```
h3 {
    font-family: "MyFontFamily";
    color: black;
    line-height: 1rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

h3.big {
    font-family: "MyFontFamily";
    color: black;
    line-height: 1.4rem;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}
```

Is there any way to only include the *changed* properties in the second selector which changed from the first selector?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing has duplicated, that is exactly what you asked for, what you should do instead is have a another class that both `small-text` and `large-text` both use called `text`

So it would be like this

```css
.text { 
    font-family: "MyFontFamily"; 
    color: black; 
} 

.small-text { 
    line-height: 1rem; 
    font-size: 1rem; 
}

h3 {
    @extend .text;
    @extend .small-text;
    
    &.big {
        @extend .large-text;
    }
}
```

So when you extend from the `small` and `large` classes it will only include the `line-height` and `font-size`